# How to pluck multiple columns in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I want to get a student's full name, but in my database, I have two different columns: `first_name` and `last_name.` I want to get both of these columns at the same time.

**Controller**

```
public function getStudentName($id) 
{
    $students = DB::table("students")->where("students_class_id", $id)
        ->pluck("first_name", "id");

    return json_encode($students);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an Eloquent model set up for your `students` table?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using laravel 5.6

Comment: I add an accessor in student model for fullname attribute but thats not working for me

Comment: And yeah i have some eloquent for student table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create custom accessor in your eloquent model like :

```php
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
   return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

Then use it in the query like :

```
$students = DB::table("students")->where("students_class_id",$id)->pluck("full_name","id");
```

Try it with eloquent like :

```php
Student::where("students_class_id",$id)->pluck("full_name","id")->toArray();
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. How do you use "full_name" as pluck argument when it is not defined anywhere? Also, I don't see the function getFullNameAttribute used anywhere in query. Could you explain this a bit more. Something seems to be missing.

Comment: Take a look to https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators

Comment: Thanks, I didn't get that the getFullNameAttribute method uses studly cased name of the colum/attribute. This makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

You could concat the first_name & last_name columns in the eloquent query to resolve the issue.

```
public function getStudentName($id) 
{
    $students = DB::table("students")
                 ->select("id", DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as name"))
                 ->where("students_class_id", $id)
                 ->pluck("name", "id");

    return json_encode($students);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir this worked for me but please remove those single quotes around first name and last name. That will not work with that. I removed it to make it work. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pick multiple columns, you can use either `only` or `except`, depending on your requirement.

```
public function getStudentName($id) 
{
    $students = DB::table("students")->where("students_class_id", $id)->select("first_name", "id")->get();

    return json_encode($students);
}
```

In tinker

```
>>> DB::table('users')->where('id', 1)->select('name', 'email')->get()
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3116
     all: [
       {#3117
         +"name": "superadmin",
         +"email": "superadmin@charmboard.com",
       },
     ],
   }
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same Situation before and i have create the model scope

```
/**
     * Scope a query to Pluck The Multiple Columns
     *
     * This is Used to Pluck the multiple Columns in the table based
     * on the existing query builder instance
     *
     * @author Manojkiran.A <manojkiran10031998@gmail.com>
     * @version 0.0.2
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @param string $keyColumn the columns Which is used to set the key of array
     * @param array $extraFileds the list of columns that need to plucked in the table
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     * @throws Illuminate\Database\QueryException
     **/
    public function scopePluckMultiple($query, string $keyColumn, array $extraFileds): \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    {
        //pluck all the id based on the query builder instance class
        $keyColumnPluck = $query->pluck($keyColumn)->toArray();

        //start @deprecated because slower than foreach

        //anonymous callback method to iterate over the each fileds of table

        // $callBcakMethod = function ($eachValue) use ($query) {
        //     $eachQuery[$eachValue] = $query->pluck($eachValue)->toArray();
        //     return $eachQuery;
        // };
        //now we are collapsing the array single time to get the propered array 

        // $extraFields = Arr::collapse(array_map($callBcakMethod, $extraFileds));

        //end @deprecated because slower than foreach

        //iterating Through All Other Fileds and Plucking it each Time
        foreach ((array)$extraFileds as  $eachFiled) {
            $extraFields[$eachFiled] =   $query->pluck($eachFiled)->toArray();
        }

        //now we are done with plucking the Required Columns
        //we need to map all the values to each key

        //get all the keys of extra fileds and sets as array key or index
        $arrayKeys = array_keys($extraFields);
        //get all the extra fileds array and mapping it to eack key
        $arrayValues = array_map(
            function ($value) use ($arrayKeys) {
                return array_combine($arrayKeys, $value);
            },
            call_user_func_array('array_map', array_merge(
                array(function () {
                    return func_get_args();
                }),
                $extraFields
            ))
        );
        //now we are done with the array now Convert it to Collection
        return new \Illuminate\Support\Collection(array_combine($keyColumnPluck, $arrayValues));
    }
```

So Paste this in Your Model

```
$whereCondition = [ ['students_class_id','=',$id] ];
$collection = Student::where($whereCondition )->pluckMultiple('id',['first_name','last_name']);

dd($collection);
```

**RESULT WILL BE**

```
Collection {#74 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "last_name" => "Doe"
      "first_name" => "John"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Explaination

Arguments:

> [First Argument] $query This Will be autoloded for all the model
>   Scopes
>
> [Second Argument] $keyColumn The Column That Hold the Id or primary
>   key [id]
>
> [Third Argument] $extraFileds The List of Columns needs to be plucked
>   [first_name,last_name]

So now we got the key and value with array

So if You want to display the first name and last name in same line

You can use the `foreach` or `map`

I have tested both but `foreach` is faster that `map`

foreach ( $collection as $idField => $columnFilelds) 
    {

```
    $fianArray[ $idField] = $columnFilelds[ 'first_name'].'-'.$columnFilelds[ 'last_name'];

}
```

So Now `dd($fianArray)`

```
array:2 [▼
  2 => "John-Doe"
  3 => "Foo-Bar"
]
```

Hope it helps

> AND ONE MORE THING YOU CAN PLUCK MULTIPLE COLUMNS NOT ONLY THE
>   `first_name,last_name`